# Associate/link records from a single table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

I have built a CRUD app using C# which is used to input cases against employees.

Im trying to figure out a way to link cases together if necessary.

e.g - A big fight breaks out

**Tom** was involved and has a case raised against him (caseID: 1)

**Mark** was also involved and has a case raised against him (caseID: 2)

**Steve** was also involved and has a case raised against him (caseID: 3)

(All the above stored in a single table)

As this was the same fight we want to link all the cases together.

How would you suggest I store this in another table?

Comment: You do not need another table. What you are doing is creating a PIVOT table from the existing table.  You can simply create the table in c# from the SQL database results.

Comment: If that possible entity (lets call it Incident) has attributes you want stored (starting/ending dates, description, location, consecuences) you will need a new table for that data and your Participants would be linked (foreign key) to it. Otherwise, you can do with no extra table, only with an Incident_Id column in your existing table.

Answer (score 0):

Yes!  You apparently need an "incident id" of some sort.  This would be a different table with one row per incident.  If the only incidents are fights, then this would be a `fights` table.

The incident id would then be related to each of the "cases" that you have.

Information about the incident would be in the `incident` table.  That would probably include information such as type, date/time, location, and so on.  In fact, what you are calling "cases" might simply be `incidentParticipants` or something like that.

Comment: Agree on calling them Participants, you may have participants but not have a case raised agains them